# Вместо миниатюры на сайте выводится видео

Tags: php, wordpress, шорткод, visual-composer

Приветствую всех! Сайт на wordpress, заметил такую особенность: если добавляешь одну запись с видео (на vimeo например) и указываешь формат видео, а вторую уже со стандартным форматом, но без указания миниатюры, то видео дублируется и на месте миниатюры второй записи. Не знаю, может это баг самой темы..
Вот код, где-то здесь косяк:

```
//  Video Post Filter                                   //
// ==================================================== //

if (!function_exists('mad_video_post_filter')) {

function mad_video_post_filter($this_post) {
    $this_post['content'] = preg_replace( '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', "[embed]$1[/embed]", strip_tags($this_post['content']));
    preg_match("!\[embed.+?\]|\[video.+?\]!", $this_post['content'], $match_video);

    if (!empty($match_video)) {
        global $wp_embed;

        $alias = $this_post['image_size'];
        $video = $match_video[0];
        $video = str_replace('[embed]', '[embed width="'. $alias[0] .'" height="'. $alias[1] .'"]', $video);

        $this_post['before_content'] = "<div class='entry-media image-overlay'>";
            $this_post['before_content'] .= do_shortcode($wp_embed->run_shortcode($video));
        $this_post['before_content'] .= "</div>";
        $this_post['content'] = str_replace($match_video[0], "", $this_post['content']);
        $this_post['content'] = apply_filters('the_content', $this_post['content']);
    }
    return $this_post;
}
}
```

Comment: Ваш код даже поправить не получается, парсер сходит с ума.

Comment: @Visman бывает, исправил оформление